# How to call a public function from another script in Unity?

Tags: unity

```
public class MoveTowards : MonoBehaviour {

    int currentStartPoint;
    private Vector3 startMarker, endMarker;
    public float speed = 1.0F;
    private float startTime;
    private float journeyLength;
    public float smooth = 5.0F;
    List<Vector3> tempPositionList = new List<Vector3>();
    List<Vector3> positionList = new List<Vector3>
        {
            new Vector3(4,0,0),
            new Vector3(4,0,2),
            new Vector3(4,0,4),
            new Vector3(2,0,4),
            new Vector3(0,0,4),
            new Vector3(-2,0,4),
            new Vector3(-4,0,4),
            new Vector3(-4,0,2),
            new Vector3(-4,0,0),
            new Vector3(-4,0,-2),
            new Vector3(-4,0,-4),
            new Vector3(-2,-0,-4),
            new Vector3(0,0,-4),
            new Vector3(2,0,-4),
            new Vector3(4,0,-4),
            new Vector3(4,0,-2),
            new Vector3(2,0,-2),
            new Vector3(0,0,-2),
            new Vector3(-2,0,-2),
            new Vector3(-2,0,0),
            new Vector3(-2,0,2),
            new Vector3(0,0,2),
            new Vector3(2,0,2),
            new Vector3(2,0,0),
            new Vector3(0,0,0)
        };
    void Start()
    {
        currentStartPoint = 0;
        SetPoints();
    }
    public void SetPoints()
    {
        startMarker = positionList[currentStartPoint];
        endMarker = positionList[currentStartPoint + 1];
        startTime = Time.time;
        journeyLength = 2;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(positionList.Count);
        float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
        float fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(positionList[currentStartPoint], positionList[currentStartPoint + 1], fracJourney);
        if (fracJourney >= 1f && currentStartPoint + 1 < positionList.Count)
        {
            currentStartPoint++;
            SetPoints();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways,

1. Drag and drop script

   ```
   public class YourOtherClass : : MonoBehaviour {
       public MoveTowards moveTowards;//assign by drag and drop in inspector
       void Start () {
           moveTowards.SetPoint();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Attach your other script on same Gameobject where your MoveTowards script attached

   ```
   public class YourOtherClass : : MonoBehaviour {
       MoveTowards moveTowards;//assign by drag and drop in inspector

       void Start () {
           moveTowards = GetComponent<MoveTowards>();
           moveTowards.SetPoint();
       }
   }
   ```
3. FindObjectOfType

   ```
   void Start () {
       //search by type, it is walid if you have only script with MoveTowards name in scene 
       //hirarcey
       MoveTowards moveTowards = FindObjectOfType<MoveTowards>();
       moveTowards.SetPoint();
   }
   ```

Comment: as you suggested i tried drag and drop getting the following error : error CS1061: Type `MoveTowards' does not contain a definition for `index' and no extension method `index' of type `MoveTowards' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: This error occurs when you try to call a method or access a class member that does not exist.

Comment: can you share complete error.

Comment: Assets/Swipe.cs(111,29): error CS1061: Type `MoveTowards' does not contain a definition for `index' and no extension method `index' of type `MoveTowards' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: that error was by my mistake but after adding script also my code is not working

Comment: share swipe script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66574/discussion-between-mohammad-faizan-khan-and-nihal-saxena).