# How to Call a function from another script?

Tags: unity, c#

I just learned in a C# tutorial that we can declare `var name = new ClassNameOfOtherScript();` to create a new class object, then use the object to call the function in that class, but it doesn't seem to be working in Unity.

Am I understanding it wrong or does it work differently in Unity?

I have a class `Cube1` this is attached to an object with `SpriteRenderer` enabled. Then I have another script `ClockController` which is not attach to any object. When I run it, the color of cube does not change to red?

```
public class Cube1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public void Rectangle()
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
    }

}
```

```
public class ClockController : MonoBehaviour
{
  
    void Start()
    {
        var cube1 = new Cube1();
        cube1.Rectangle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would the colour of your *existing* Cube1 object change when you called the colour change function on a *new* Cube1 object? (ie. NOT the one that already exists in your scene/project) [Did you try searching for past answers about how to get a reference to an existing object to call a method on it](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/149142/39518)?

Comment: Tested both code and noticed the different, indeed putting the title getting a reference on(existing) object would be more appropriate. Been learning C# fundamental tutorial for sometime yet I do not realize I'm on the wrong direction regarding the usage of "new" operator. Thank again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are doing `var cube1 = new Cube1();` which is how you would make an object in C#, but since it is Unity, and this is a MonoBehaviour, you are not supposed to make it like that.

Instead, make a new `GameObject` and attach the `Cube1` script to it.

```
void Start()
{
    // make a new gameobject.
    GameObject gameObject = new GameObject();

    // adding a SpriteRenderer as your `Cube1` will try to access it.
    // -- please also see the bottom note of the answer. --
    gameObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    // attach a Cube1 script to it and store the reference to it in a var. 
    Cube1 cube = gameObject.AddComponent<Cube1>();

    // call the function on that cube.
    cube.Rectangle();
}
```

Sidenote, if you don't make an object in the scene that holds the ClockController, it won't execute the `Start()` method.

---

When you already have an existing `GameObject` (instead of making a new one) that has a script you want to access, you can use `gameObject.GetComponent<Cube1>()` , store it in a variable (if necessary) and access it that way. You just need to get that specific `GameObject` to begin with.

---

Extra info on component dependencies:

As pointed out by @DMGregory, `cube.Rectangle()` will try to find/access a `SpriteRenderer` on the `cube` object, which would have to be added first. You could add `[RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]` which means that whenever you add a `Cube1` script to a `GameObject`, the *required component is added aswell if it is not already there*.

I'd suggest to take a look at the docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html

Alternatives would probably be making sure in your Cube1 script that at some point a SpriteRenderer is attached, but that's all going off-topic I think.

Comment: Note that since `Cube1.Rectangle()` tries to get a reference to an attached `SpriteRenderer` component, it does not make sense to call this on a new object that has no `SpriteRenderer` on it, as shown in this answer. The `as Cube1` is also unnecessary — the return type is already `Cube1`

Comment: Ah thanks, I was not sure about the `as Cube1` part so looked up the docs (and saw it there). Will update my answer. Sharp one on the `SpriteRenderer`, guess I was too focussed on only answering how to call the function.

Comment: Note that the `as` is shown in the docs only for the overloads that take a type or string as an argument. It is not present in the example for the generic version that you're using here.